# How to use Social Plugins

Tags: plugins, fbml

Just started a page for my business. I have NO IDEA where to put the codes for something as simple as a "like" button to appear on my page. I don't understand what URL I'm supposed to include in the "href" section. I'm not even sure what that is. I really need help...

Comment: I think this is going to be difficult for anyone to answer as it sounds like you are not a developer and this is going to require some programming knowledge i think

Answer (score 0):

I googled "facebook like button tutorial", the first result is:

http://developer.practicalecommerce.com/articles/1857-Two-Easy-Ways-to-Add-the-Facebook-Like-Button-to-Product-Detail-Pages

Looks pretty comprehensive.